# Remove item from List<string[]> or get index of any item at any position

Tags: c#, collections, generic-list

I am trying to remove item from  `List<string[]>` but remove property is not working but if I use `RemoveAt(0)` (any int hardcoded value) then it's working ... What could be problem. Can anyone help me?

Here is my code...

```
List<string[]> ipcol1 = new List<string[]>();
ipcol1.Add(new string[] { "test1" });
ipcol1.Add(new string[] { "test2" });
ipcol1.Add(new string[] { "test3" });
ipcol1.Add(new string[] { "test4" });
ipcol1.Remove(new string[] { "test1" });

int i = ipcol1.IndexOf(new string[] { "test4" });
ipcol1.RemoveAt(i);
```

Or if I am trying to take index of perticular item then it's giving me (-1) as result ... If I can get index of that problem then my problem can resolve... Please help me.

Comment: The string array you add to the List is not the same as the one you use in `IndexOf`. They may have the same value, but they are not the same instance. Since Arrays are *reference* types, none of your items will be the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `SequenceEqual` when comparing arrays:

```
  List<string[]> ipcol1 = new List<string[]>();
  ipcol1.Add(new string[] { "test1" });
  ipcol1.Add(new string[] { "test2" });
  ipcol1.Add(new string[] { "test3" });
  ipcol1.Add(new string[] { "test4" });

  ipcol1.RemoveAll(array => array.SequenceEqual(new string[] { "test1" }));
```

Or (in case you want to remove any record which contains `"test1"` somewhere in array):

```
  ipcol1.RemoveAll(array => array.Any(item => item == "test1")));
```

The reason is that two arrays are equal if they have the *same reference* :

```
  string[] array1 = new string[0];
  string[] array2 = array1;
  string[] array3 = new string[0];

  // "Yes" - array1 and array2 reference to the instance
  Console.WriteLine((array1 == array2) ? "Yes" : "No");
  // "No" - array1 and array3 are references to different instances
  Console.WriteLine((array1 == array3) ? "Yes" : "No");

  // "Yes" - array1 and array3 are equal sequences
  Console.WriteLine((array1.SequenceEqual(array3)) ? "Yes" : "No");
```

Answer (score 0):

The arrays are reference types. The below code fails because you are comparing the references of two separate instances.

```
ipcol1.Remove(new string[] { "test1" });
```

You can use [SequenceEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) to compare collections.